# If one were to code a digital map such as Google Maps using Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path, how will the nodes be represented/coded?

Tags: maps, shortest-path, dijkstra

How are the nodes going to be represented? In a map, are these nodes every point on it? Need to know more about the nodes in Dijkstra Algorithm and how to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

The nodes and paths are essentially ambiguous and declarative of what you want them to represent. Is a node an intersection? (scaling on a city size) Is the node a city? (Scaling on a provincial/state, country or continent scale).

The paths would need some sort of weighting between them as well. So if you're picking intersections for nodes what is the weight between node A & B vs. the weight between node B & C? I assume you'd want to use time but you don't have that data readily available do you?

There's more challenges than just nodes I think... without a database of weighting data to run short-path algorithm against you're dead in the water.

In a more abstract way of looking at it you need to determine your nodes (points probably using lat/long coords) and then determine weighting between each node that can be reached. So using the A B C idea again can node A reach node C directly? Can it reach it through B?

```
      4       3
A ------- B--------
  \                \
   -----------------C
            8

A -> B = 4
B -> C = 3
A -> C = 8
A -> B -> C = 7
```